# Windows RT and Toast Notification behavior

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, notifications

Hello,
I'm testing the Toast Notification for a Windows RT application. I set the 'Toast Capable' to yes on the manifest file, and I create a sample method called by a button, with this code Inside :

> var toastTemplate =
>   ToastNotificationManager.GetTemplateContent(ToastTemplateType.ToastImageAndText01);
>
> var text = toastTemplate.GetElementsByTagName("text")[0] as
>   XmlElement; text.AppendChild(toastTemplate.CreateTextNode("This is the
>   test !"));
>
> var image = toastTemplate.GetElementsByTagName("image")[0] as
>   XmlElement; image.SetAttribute("src", String.Format("ms-appx:///{0}",
>   "Images/rss_logo.png"));
>
> ToastNotification toastNotification = new
>   ToastNotification(toastTemplate); ToastNotifier toastNotifier =
>   ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier();
>   toastNotifier.Show(toastNotification);

When I cleck the button, the notification appears on the top right of the screen, but without text and image... Just the box, with the logo of application.

Could you please tell me where I'm wrong ?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About the first problem (text not appear) :

In the Manifest file 'Package.manifest', I set Foreground text to 'Dark'.
 The problem was that by default the text Foreground is white.

The problem about Image :

My image was not in correct format, and not in the right directory. In the MS QuickStart([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh868254(v=win.10).aspx][1]), it said:

> " Versions of this step are shown for each image source. Images must
> be less than 200 KB in size and smaller than 1024 x 1024 pixels. "

Comment: have you achieved what you desired or this question is still open ?

Comment: Yes, it is solved. But I cannot close it until tomorrow... (the system refuse and ask me to wait 2 days before close it).